# How to work with foreign keys when using Entity Framework code first

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I create a `Menu` class that has a self-relation.

```
Public Class Menu
    Sub New()
        Me.lstmenu = New List(Of Menu)
    End Sub
    Property MenuID As Integer
    Property Title As String
    Property Description As String
    Property URL As String
    Property lstmenu As ICollection(Of Menu)
End Class
```

Entity Framework code-first creates a table from this class with a self relation.

[image: SQL table made by code first]

I want to write a query with Linq to return me all menus that their foreign key are null but all I have is a lstmenu that hold a list of menus. And I can't find any FK column to use in my query.

Please help me how to write a query to find all records that their foreign key are null.

Comment: Thanks to @marc_c for edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is declare the FK property in your `Menu` entity as nullable integer and the navigation property that represent the other end of your relationship. The following solution is using Data Annotations:

```
Public Class Menu
    Sub New()
        Me.lstmenu = New List(Of Menu)
    End Sub
    Property MenuID As Integer

    <ForeignKey("ParentMenu")>
    Property ParentMenuID As Integer? 'Change the FK name and nav. property name at your convinience
    Property ParentMenu As Menu

    Property Title As String
    Property Description As String
    Property URL As String
    Property lstmenu As ICollection(Of Menu)
End Class
```

If you want to configure your relationship using Fluent Api to avoid using attributes in your model, you can also do the same overriding `OnModelCreating` method of your context:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnModelCreating(ByVal modelBuilder As DbModelBuilder)

    modelBuilder.Entity(Of Menu)().
    HasOptional(Function(t) t.ParentMenu).
    WithMany(Function(t) t.lstmenu).
    HasForeignKey(Function(t) t.ParentMenuId)

End Sub
```

Now you can verify in your queries if a menu have associated a parent menu checking if the FK property is null or not

Comment: Thanks a lot @octavioccl your first solution works perfect. I do this: <code> 'Public Class Menu
    Sub New()
        Me.lstmenu = New List(Of Menu)
    End Sub
    Property MenuID As Integer
    <ForeignKey("lstmenu")>
    Property ParentMenuID As Integer?
    Property Title As String
    Property Description As String
    Property URL As String
    Property lstmenu As ICollection(Of Menu)
End Class' </code> and it works well. thanks again